# Any standard size for a signature and/or logo on invoices or receipts?

Tags: print-design, page-layout, template-design

I want to make a master layout for invoices and receipts which will include a company logo and signature of authorized person in (png/jpeg format).

So what should be or what is the standard size for brand logo and signature?

Comment: I very much doubt there is a "Standard size" - just use whatever looks right. unless there is a specific brand style guide for the company, then use that.

Comment: okay i will do like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There simply isn't a standard size**

I know it's not the answer you want to hear, but it is the answer to this question.

One company might adopt a standard size, but that will be because that standard size worked for *them* dependent upon the layout and design of their invoices, the legibility and aesthetics of the logo at various sizes, and lots of other factors.
The fact remains, *there is no global standard*.

EDIT: I think it's worth pointing out (re @Digital Lightcraft comment) that of course if a particular company has developed a style guide then of course that will dictate the size of these things, so in that instance there will be a standard, but of course only for that s*pecific company*, and not, as OP was suggesting, *globally*.

Answer (score 0):

Each branding project comes with its own standard, which yourself or others are setting. So whatever works i guess. Make your logo 5cm wide and print the template. If you can't read it, make it bigger until it looks right. And that you can then call "standard".

Answer (score -1):

In my company the standard is 600x116px, but as "Lightcraft" said there isn't a standard for everyone; it depends on the companies own guidelines.

Comment: and what about e-signature